# Javascript get data attribute from selected option in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following html:

```
<td class="" data-id="46" contenteditable="true">
<select class="form-control">
   <option data-key="end" selected>Opt1</option>
   <option data-key="operator_transfer">Opt2</option>
   <option data-key="process_script">Opt3</option>
</select>
</td>
```

I need to get data attribute of the selected option. I am trying to do it that way:

```
var cell = $row.find(':nth-child(4)');
dataattr = cell[0].getAttribute('data-id');
var selectObject = cell.find("select");
if(selectObject.length){// if it is a select
    localobj[dataattr] = selectObject[0].getAttribute('data-key');//val(); previously it was val() here but now I want data-key
}
```

I tried with this:

```
$(selectObject/*need to insert something here*/ + ' option:selected').data('key');
```

but it is showing me an error saying that it is an object Object. I need to insert something after selectObject. Any ideas how to fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you also using jQuery?

Comment: yes, jQuery present

Comment: `selectObject[0]` is getting you the `<select class="form-control">` element. You want the selected `<option>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `$('.form-control').children('option:selected').attr('data-key')` using jquery function [`attr()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiL9KyH6KbUAhXJQI8KHdwjAUgQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fattr%2F&usg=AFQjCNE1qhpJI2G8J0vSJXrZ_Vf8dTKrTg&sig2=xxxQkZWF59vhcT2jrW3PhA)

```js
console.log($('.form-control').children('option:selected').attr('data-key'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="" data-id="46" contenteditable="true">
<select class="form-control">
   <option data-key="end" selected>Opt1</option>
   <option data-key="operator_transfer">Opt2</option>
   <option data-key="process_script">Opt3</option>
</select>
</td>
```

For your code you could do like this

```
var cell = $row.find(':nth-child(4)');
dataattr = cell[0].getAttribute('data-id');
var selectObject = cell.find("select");
if(selectObject.length){// if it is a select
    localobj[dataattr] = selectObject[0].getAttribute('data-key');
}
$(selectObject).children('option:selected').data('key');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the [jQuery **data()**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method with the right selector, like this:

```
$('select option:selected').data('key');
```

**Demo:**

```js
var key = $('select option:selected').data('key');
console.log(key);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="" data-id="46" contenteditable="true">
<select class="form-control">
   <option data-key="end" selected>Opt1</option>
   <option data-key="operator_transfer">Opt2</option>
   <option data-key="process_script">Opt3</option>
</select>
</td>
```

And you can update your code like this:

```
if (selectObject.length) { // if it is a select
  localobj[dataattr] = selectObject[0].getAttribute('data-key');
}
$(selectObject).find('option:selected').data('key');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.form-control').change(function(){
alert($('.form-control').find(':selected').attr('data-key'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="" data-id="46" contenteditable="true">
<select class="form-control">
   <option data-key="end" selected>Opt1</option>
   <option data-key="operator_transfer">Opt2</option>
   <option data-key="process_script">Opt3</option>
</select>
</td>
```